# Count only rows where two columns both contain one of a specific set of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to build a formula in Excel 2010 to count rows in which columns A1:A1005 and D1:D1005 both contain either `Y`, `N` or `N/A`.  I want to exclude rows where both columns do not contain some combination of those three values.  So, for example:

```
A   B  C  D
N         N
Y         N
N/A
```

would have a count of 2.  How can I do this?

The closest I have come is:

```
COUNTIFS('Analysis'!A1:A1005,“(N,Y,N/A)”,'Analysis'!D1:D1005,“(N,Y,N/A)”)
```

Comment: Your question refers to column U, but your example refers to column D.  Also, the question refers to "NA" but the example refers to "N/A" (and if you are testing for the error condition rather than a stored text value, that will be neither and tested in a different way).  Also, please clarify the relationship between the two columns.  Do they contain identical values?  For example, can one column contain "Y" and the other be blank, and if so, which rule applies (count the row because it contains "Y" or exclude it because it contains blank)?

Comment: I want to count the row only if columns A and D have any combination of "Y, N, or N/A" as a value; and exclude all others including blank rows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Countif with an OR expression like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A20,{"Y","N","N/A"}))
```

That looks at one column. It is not clear from the question how you want to treat values in the other column. Options are

sum counts where a match is found in the same row of both A and D:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A20,{"Y","N","N/A"},D1:D20,{"Y","N","N/A"}))
```

add up counts in A plus counts in D:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A20,{"Y","N","N/A"}),COUNTIFS(D1:D20,{"Y","N","N/A"}))
```

Test with a small data sample until you have the result you expect.

[image]

Edit: if the desired result is 2, then use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:$A$20="y")+($A$1:$A$20="n")+($A$1:$A$20="n/a"))*($D$1:$D$20="y")+($D$1:$D$20="n")+($D$1:$D$20="n/a"))
```

Comment: The result I am looking for would return a count of 2.  I want to count the row only if columns A and D have any combination of "Y, N, or N/A" as a value; and exclude all others including blank rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: I added another formula that calculates that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding a helper column, which you can hide if you find it annoying, you can add this formula to an adjacent column:

```
=IF(AND(OR($A2="Y",$A2="N",$A2="N/A"),OR($D2="Y",$D2="N",$D2="N/A")),1,"")
```

drag it down to as many rows as you need, and then sum that column.  I've tested this against your example, and it appears to work.

Comment: Have you tested that? First, you don't need a `=` inside the comparison string. Second, Countifs uses AND not OR for multiple conditions.

Comment: Teylyn, this is an example straight from Excel help: =COUNTIFS(B2:B5,"=Yes",C2:C5,"=Yes").

Comment: I just said you don't need it, not that it's wrong to use it. It creates typing work.

Comment: Looks like I need an OR formula with multiple conditions.  I want to count the row only if columns A and D have any combination of "Y, N, or N/A" as a value; and exclude all others including blank rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: Teylyn, you are absolutely correct, the equal sign inside the quotes is not necessary.  I guess MS just throws that in their example to cause their users to do unnecessary typing.  My apologies.